# Tag synonym request: [mortal-kombat-9] and [mortal-kombat-2011]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The most recently released Mortal Kombat game is simply titled (confusingly enough) "Mortal Kombat." It's the 9th game in the series, so it's been tagged here as [mortal-kombat-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-9) but in several places online, it's also referred to as [mortal-kombat-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-2011) (which is what I was originally searching for on the site proper). Could we get a tag synonym for these two for clarity's sake and search visibility?

Answer (score 1):

This has been done. Let's hope it helps!